# Reinstall in current partitions

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I've well and truely messed up my ubuntu server installation. However, I have a few gigabytes of media on a partition I would like to preserve. I believe I messed up the Ubuntu install and then the grub install(palm to face). I've booted using a bootable usb, and I can run `fdisk`, but not `grub-install`. Here are the current partitions on the disk(abbreviated):

```
/dev/sda1      2028    1050623 ...... EFI System
/dev/sda2   1050624    1550335 ...... Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   1550336 1951973376 ...... Linux LVM
```

What I take this to mean, is that the first partition should be the `grub` installer, the second partition is the bootable ubuntu installation, and the third is my main partition.

Here's my plan of attack:

1. Install grub into first partition -- how? `apt-get` doesn't work
2. Install ubuntu from the usb stick